# Are there any cloud based file comparison service?

Tags: xml, compare, cloud, saas

I have two huge XML files to compare. I have tried almost all of the recommendations in various similar StackOverflow questions. Windows based applications run out of memory and become unresponsive. So I'm looking for a cloud based solution where I can upload my XML files and do the comparison with the power of the cloud.

Comment: may be you can provision high end VM and run the same windows application there and it may complete it without crashing. or is there an option to split the files and then compare the smaller sized chunks ?

Comment: As you suggested I provisioned an 8 core 112GB memory Windows Server 2012 from Azure and started the process on this powerful machine. I tried both with Altova DiffDog Enterprise Edition and DiffMerge with no success. They both became unresponsive for several minutes. I think it is not with the CPU or the memory, at least I can see that now, so thank you for your suggestion @Aravind. Even though the files are not that gigantic (40MBs each) I will try to chunk them.

Comment: oh ok. Then I guess it has got something to do with the file or those softwares are not equipped to handle that file.

Comment: I found a software called Beyond Compare http://www.scootersoftware.com/ It worked much better. I finally had results using my single core 8GB laptop. It sorts the files first so I believe this affects the performance. I wanted to share for those in search of an XML comparison solution. Highly recommended.

Comment: glad that you got it working.